# Locally rendering client-side HTML page in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, puppeteer

I am scraping web pages using node-fetch but I need to render some of the pages to get the complete content. Ideally, I would fetch the pre-rendered html then have that html be rendered and returned as html.

I have looked into rendertron, but I want something lightweight and don't want to deploy it to a server. Rendertron also gets blocked on certain sites that I am scraping.

What is the most elegant and lightweight way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want an image file of the page?

Comment: @AminadavGlickshtein I want to have a local server that takes the pre-rendered page and returns the fully rendered page for scraping with cheerio or similar packages. So I just want the html of the page after the JavaScript is executed.

Comment: https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom